# Eclipse CDT default makefile: read CXXFLAGS variable?

Tags: eclipse-cdt

Is there an option to force the generated makefile read the `CXXFLAGS` and `CFLAGS` variables and use them as most of makefiles do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse CDT generated makefiles have the following lines included:

`-include ../makefile.init`

`-include ../makefile.defs`

You can create the file makefile.defs in which you define CFLAGS or CXXFLAGS and then go to project `Properties` -> `C++ Build Properties` -> `Settings` -> GCC or G++ compiler -> `Miscellaneous`. Here you can add your $(CFLAGS) or $(CXXFLAGS) option in the `Other flags` field.

This should add your additional options to the compiler command line.

Comment: I'm not sure about on what you mean with the makefile.defs and such, they cannot affect the g++ command being invoked. But the trick with Other flags worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it ends up in your .cproject file, so you will need to check that in to source control if you want other developers to see it. I had thought it generally advisable not to check that file in. It would be nice if you could just add a flag in makefile.init or makefile.defs.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by not selecting the "Use default build command" radio box in the C/C++ Build Setting.

Specify custom Build command: make -f Makefile.   You can add additional compiler options in the $CCFLAGS defined in the targeted Makefile.

[image]